# Unlocking index without losing quality? Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, image-quality

So i am trying to edit an icon pack that has an index lock on it.

I know to unlock it you go to image > mode > rgb color.

However doing this drastically reduces the image quality.

> [image: Below is the original still with the index layer:]

Apologies the icon above is white (on a white background)!

[image: Here it is unlocked and edited with loss of quality :]

The original is a .PNG and the saved edited version is a PNG.

The original file is only 1kb not that I'd think that would make any difference. But when I save it there seems to be some little specks that appear eg the very top line on the left it seems to protude. And the bottom right inside there is a dot of white.

All I've done is unlocked the index and re-saved and it just seems to deteriate in quality.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The two look exactly the same. Can you post an example of this reduction of quality?

Answer (score 4):

if you try to open your icon and save it as jpeg you might get a reduction of quality because of the jpeg compression.

Assuming the original format is GIF, if you open and save it again as GIF there should not be any loss of quality, unless you reduce the amount of colors (when saving) that were in the original file.

Inside Photoshop there should be no visible quality loss during edition.